# Question related to container construct and release

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, constructor, stl

I have written a customized hash map, whose value contains an `std::vector`. And it caused core dump in real environment. There is a simplified example below. There are three questions:

1. Why vector size doesn't change to zero when I called the destruct function `~Value()`? Does this program really release the memory allocated by vector before when I call the destruct function? And when I gdb attaches to this program, it's `__M_start` and `__M_finish` pointer still point to the same address.
2. `Add1` and `Add2` both have memory problems. `Add1` won't call the construct function of vector, when I push_back `int*` to the vector of `Value` which has been `erase` before, it might be added to an illegal address. When I want to use the `Add2` function to call the copy construct function, it might cause segment fault. Why it is still not working with `Add2`?
3. How should I change my program if I still want to use my customized map instead of std::map?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <set>
using namespace std;


class Value
{
public:
    // Value()
    // {
    // }
    // Value(const Value &obj): stArr(obj.stArr)
    // {
    //     cout<<"Call copy construct"<<endl;
    // }

    vector<int*> stArr;
};

class CustomMap
{
public:

    // normal way
    void Add1(int key, const Value& val)
    {
        stArrVal[key] = val;
    }

    // placement new
    void Add2(int key, const Value& val)
    {
        new (&stArrVal[key]) Value(val);
        // stArrVal[key] = val;
    }

    // void Add2(int key, const Value& val)
    // {
    //     new (&stArrVal[key]) Value(val);
    // }

    void Erase(int key)
    {
        stArrVal[key].~Value();
        // stArrVal[key].stArr.clear();
        cout<<stArrVal[key].stArr.size()<<endl;
    }

    void Search(int key, Value *&pstVal)
    {
        pstVal = &stArrVal[key];
    }

    Value stArrVal[100];
};

void PrintValAddress(Value *pVal)
{
    for (const auto & val : pVal->stArr)
    {
        cout<<&val<<", ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}



int main()
{
    vector<int> arr;
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(3);

    std::map<int, Value> stlMap;
    CustomMap customMap;
    Value* value = new Value();
    Value* value2 = new Value();
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    value->stArr.push_back(&a);
    value->stArr.push_back(&b);
    value->stArr.push_back(&c);
    value2->stArr.push_back(&a);
    value2->stArr.push_back(&b);
    value2->stArr.push_back(&c);
    // value2->stArr.push_back(&d);

    stlMap.insert(pair<int, Value>(1, *value));
    Value &stlV = stlMap[1];

    Value *pstCusV = NULL;

    customMap.Add1(1, *value);
    customMap.Add2(2, *value);
    customMap.Search(1, pstCusV);
    PrintValAddress(pstCusV);
    customMap.Search(2, pstCusV);
    PrintValAddress(pstCusV);

    // Release
    customMap.Erase(1);
    customMap.Erase(2);

    // this line will cause segment fault.
    // int* arr2 = new int[1024*1024];

    customMap.Search(2, pstCusV);
    // 1. still size 3
    PrintValAddress(pstCusV);

    // int* arr1 = new int[10];

    customMap.Add1(1, *value2);
    customMap.Add2(2, *value2);
    customMap.Search(1, pstCusV);
    PrintValAddress(pstCusV);
    customMap.Search(2, pstCusV);
    PrintValAddress(pstCusV);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xa14090, 0xa14098, 0xa140a0, 
0xa14160, 0xa14168, 0xa14170, 
3
3
0xa14160, 0xa14168, 0xa14170, 
0xa14090, 0xa14098, 0xa140a0, 
0xa14160, 0xa14168, 0xa14170,
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. Because it is not needed, all destructor should do is free memory. 2. You are doing something very strange. Why you use array to emulate map? There is no way to delete element from array. Destructor shouldn't be called directly, etc. 3. Implement equvalent to std::map, i.e. when element is erased, it should be not just destructed, but not available at all.

Comment: Hi! I need some clarification.
1. What is the purpose of this hashmap? Why do you put int* (pointer to int) values to a vector? Vector won't free these pointers automatically.
2. Add2 is bad, it tries to construct Value on an already initialized memory area.

Comment: I'm not trying to delete elements from array. I just want to release memory allocated by std::vector. I'm trying to use an array to emulate a hashmap, which contains a std::vector, and it doesn't matter which value I store in this container(`int*` in this question).